# How to develop .Net services when not logged in as administrator

Tags: .net, service

Is there an easy way to develop services in .Net when I'm not running as administrator? There are a couple problems I encountered. First of all when debugging, you can't just press F5 from visual studio, as it says services must first be installed and then run from the services administrator tool.  The problem is that without administrator rights, I can't create or control services.  We are using Windows Server 2008 with AD to manage our users. Is there a specific set of rights I can give users so that they can add/remove/start/stop services?   What if we only want developers accessing services they actually created themselves?  Also, once the service is running, what's the best way to debug it. Assuming the service is started, and already running, Visual Studio could attach to the already running process, is there a better way so that debugging can begin from the entry point of the service?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I tend to do when working with services is create a console app to run the code from during development.  This means you have to have the service as a thin layer over the code that does the work, so you can call that code from your console app, but that's not a bad idea anyway.

I know that doesn't exactly answer your question, but hopefully might be helpful!

Comment: This is a good idea but it's also useful to be able to debug the service itself, as it may be running under a builtin or different user account.

Answer (score 1):

Your users need permission to log on as a service.

Use Administrative Tools, Local Security Policy, Local Policies, User Rights Assignment.

Add your user(s) to the list in "Log on as a service".

You cannot restrict this right to specific services.

For debugging - one trick I have used is to add a `Sleep(20000);` in the early logic to give the debugger time to attach.  You have to make sure that your service keeps telling the Service Control Maanger that it is awake (ServiceStatus = SERVICE_START_PENDING), or it will be assumed dead, and killed.

Answer (score 1):

Kibbee,

This is actually a problem that I have sort of encountered myself. The simplest way to work around the Visual Studio issues is to create an app that works right over the top of the service level. This could be a simple console app that makes the calls the same way that the service does. If done properly this will work identically to the service, without actually being a service, which will allow your developers to test and debug properly.

You can actually give users the ability to run a service without being an administrator, now whether or not you can isolate them to specific services I am not sure.

Comment: I thought about this. It wouldn't be that difficult to create a small GUI that would start/stop the "service", and also that would display messages sent back from the service (by registering on events). I think I may go this direction as it seems to make development a lot easier, without giving users more rights than they need.

Comment: @Kibbee that's the basic idea. Most of the services that I have written are running code from other libraries with very little code in the actual service itself.